# How to create multiple tables in SQL

Tags: python, database, datatables

If I have a list that contains like 50 elements, how can I create 50 independent tables for my data base?

My code is like that:

for ticker in B3tickers():

```
    cur.execute( 'create table ? '\
'(data datetime primary key, '\
'open REAL, '\
'high REAL, '\
'low REAL, '\
'close REAL, '\
'adjclose REAL)')
```

B3tickers is a list with all Brazilian companies symbol.

Comment: Which SQL database are you running?

Comment: SQlite 3, but thanks I've already done what I was supposed to

Comment: As an aside, 50 identically structured tables in a relational database may not be optimal design.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a single sql script itself not run an execute aka:

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Customer]') AND type in (N'U'))

BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
   column1 datatype,
   column2 datatype,
   column3 datatype,
);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

After some guys helped me on another question I did solve the problem: Here is the code:

```
for i in range(0,len(B3tickers())):
    name = B3tickers()[i]
    cur.execute( 'CREATE TABLE {name} '\
'(data datetime primary key, '\
'Open REAL, '\
'high REAL, '\
'low REAL, '\
'close REAL, '\
'adjclose REAL)'.format(name=name))
```